# Instant validation with JavaScript - not sure where to start

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, email-validation

```js
//PENDING
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14pt;
  /* 1em */
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(./img/bg);
}
#cog {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: -5%;
}
section.hero {
  padding: none;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
section.hero h1.heroText {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 100;
}
section.hero h1.subText {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
}
div.footer {
  font-size: 1.75em;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
input.nicerInput {
  height: 50px;
  width: 25%;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  display: inline-block;
}
input.submitButton {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 56px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #5CCF58;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: -6px;
  top: -1px;
  -webkit-transition: linear all 1s;
  -moz-transition: linear all 1s;
  -mos-transition: linear all 1s;
}
input.submitButton:hover {
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #28CD20;
  -webkit-transition: linear all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: linear all 0.5s;
  -mos-transition: linear all 0.5s;
}
input.submitButton:active {
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #21B71C;
  -webkit-transition: linear all 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: linear all 0.1s;
  -mos-transition: linear all 0.1s;
}
.errorMsg {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  display: none;
}
.fa-spin-custom {
  -webkit-animation: spin 7500ms infinite linear;
  animation: spin 7500ms infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
.fa-7x {
  font-size: 7.5em !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <meta name="author" content="Olly John">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Stephen John Eyecare, Stephen John Opticians, Worcester, Opticians, Opticions">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/styles.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Stephen John Eyecare - Coming Soon</title>
</head>

<body>
  <i class="fa fa-7x fa-cog fa-spin-custom" id="cog"></i>
  <section class="hero">
    <h1 class="heroText">We'll be coming <strong>really soon!</strong></h1>
    <h1 class="subText">If you'd like to be notified when we go live, please submit your e-mail address using the field below</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="field">
    <form action="" name="form" method="post">
      <div class="form">
        <input type="text" class="nicerInput" name="input" id="input" placeholder="you@youremail.com">
        <input type="submit" class="submitButton" disabled="true" value="submit" id="sub">
        <br>
        <br>
        <span class="errorMsg" id="empty">Please make sure to enter your e-mail address before submitting it to us. <br></span>
        <span class="errorMsg" id="format">The e-mail address you entered is invalid.  Please enter an e-mail address in the format johndoe@email.com</span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </section>
  <div class="footer">Stephen John Eyecare</div>
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/src/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Use jQuery to validate?-->
</body>

</html>
```

Hi folks,

I've been asked by my father to make a landing page for his website that he's having made and he just wants something to put on the host so it's not being wasted as he's already bought the space and domain but there's been a setback with the development of the site so he's just asked me to quickly make something that says the main site's coming soon and gives people the ability to sign up to be notified when it goes live. 
I've done all the front end stuff and I've started looking at the validation side of things for the 'form' and I can't make heads or tails of it so I was hoping someone could offer some insight as to what I need to do for it if you'd be so kind. 
The code for the page thus far is in the snippet.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I sympathize with your situation, but SO is probably not the place for this kind of help. You'd best either find a RL friend to help you out, run through some tutorials on building web apps, or cutting down a lot on scope for your temporary website (e.g. just some text, images, and a mailto link).

Comment: What kind of validation do you exactly want to perform? That is the question. You should consider a [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) so as not to reinvent the wheel;

Comment: share your javascript. You have used validate(this.value) on blur and keyup event. May be we could help you with that. Show what you have tried so far

Comment: I would use the jQuery Validation Plugin

Comment: I'd completely forgotten about the onblur() and onKeyUp() things I'd put in - I was following a tutorial for them but it didn't work so I got rid of the JS I'd written for it and I guess I just forgot to take them out..

The idea of the validation is that, if the field is left empty, the first message will show, reminding the user to put something in the field.  If the field's filled but it's not a valid e-mail address, the second message will show, telling the user what they put is invalid and if what they put is valid, the button will be enabled and they can send it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code it will work validation.. **Don't forgot to put main jquery and validate min files**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <meta name="author" content="Olly John">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Stephen John Eyecare, Stephen John Opticians, Worcester, Opticians, Opticions">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/styles.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Stephen John Eyecare - Coming Soon</title>
  <style>
  body {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14pt;
  /* 1em */
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(./img/bg);
}
#cog {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: -5%;
}
section.hero {
  padding: none;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
section.hero h1.heroText {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 100;
}
section.hero h1.subText {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
}
div.footer {
  font-size: 1.75em;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
input.nicerInput {
  height: 50px;
  width: 25%;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  display: inline-block;
}
input.submitButton {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 56px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #5CCF58;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: -6px;
  top: -1px;
  -webkit-transition: linear all 1s;
  -moz-transition: linear all 1s;
  -mos-transition: linear all 1s;
}
input.submitButton:hover {
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #28CD20;
  -webkit-transition: linear all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: linear all 0.5s;
  -mos-transition: linear all 0.5s;
}
input.submitButton:active {
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #21B71C;
  -webkit-transition: linear all 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: linear all 0.1s;
  -mos-transition: linear all 0.1s;
}
.errorMsg {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  display: none;
}
.fa-spin-custom {
  -webkit-animation: spin 7500ms infinite linear;
  animation: spin 7500ms infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
.fa-7x {
  font-size: 7.5em !important;
}
label .error{color:red;}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <i class="fa fa-7x fa-cog fa-spin-custom" id="cog"></i>
  <section class="hero">
    <h1 class="heroText">We'll be coming <strong>really soon!</strong></h1>
    <h1 class="subText">If you'd like to be notified when we go live, please submit your e-mail address using the field below</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="field">
    <form action="" name="form"  id="sample_frm" method="post">
      <div class="form">
        <input type="text" class="nicerInput" name="user_email" id="input" placeholder="you@youremail.com">
        <input type="submit" class="submitButton" value="submit" id="sub">
         </div>
    </form>
  </section>
  <div class="footer">Stephen John Eyecare</div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  
 <script>
  $( "#sample_frm" ).validate({
  rules: {
user_email: {
  required: true,
  email: true
}
  },
  messages:
  {
  user_email:{
  required:"Enter email id", //custom error message
  email: "valid email id"
  }
  }
});
</script>
  <!-- Use jQuery to validate?-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the help!  How would I have it with the error messages as well?

Comment: replace withis script part  <script>
  $( "#sample_frm" ).validate({
  rules: {
    user_email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  },
  messages:
  {
  user_email:{
  required:"Enter email id",
  email: "valid email id"
  }
  }
});
    </script>

Comment: I meant with the error messages I'd put in before, the two spans in my original code?  Or is that not possible?

Comment: its possible for that you need to write code in CSS

Comment: So what would it be?  Just set the display to inline instead of none if the error's there?

Comment: Yeah, I can do the CSS myself.  Do I just put the CSS where you put the custom message(s)?

Comment: you can change the error message position, color with the help of  inspect element..